# Refresh ListAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, view, listadapter

I am having some problem when trying to refresh the list view in Android. This is my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transaction_rec);
    context = this;
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    builtListView();
}

public void builtListView() {
    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
            mDbHelper.open());

    ArrayList<TransactionRecModel> trans_list = trc
            .getTransactionRec(session_userID);

    for (int i = 0; i < trans_list.size(); i++) {
        String date = trans_list.get(i).getDate();
        String categoryName = trans_list.get(i).getCategory();
        String transDesc = trans_list.get(i).getTransDescription();

        TransactionRecModel _TransModel = new TransactionRecModel();

        _TransModel.setDate(date);
        _TransModel.setCategory(categoryName);
        _TransModel.setTransDescription(transDesc);

        _translist.add(_TransModel);
    }
    // Set the data into listview
    listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

And I create a rebuildListView method to set listAdapter to null and call the buildListView method again:

```
public void rebuildListView() {
    listview.setAdapter(null);
    builtListView();
}
```

And when I successfully insert the record into database, I refresh the list view by calling the rebuildListView:

```
TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
                mDbHelper.open());
        if (trc.addTransactionRec(trm)) {
            Toast.makeText(TransactionRec.this,
                    "Transaction Record Added successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mDbHelper.close();
            txtTransDesc.setText("");
            txtAmount.setText("");
            txtDate.setText("");

            // Refresh the list view after record added
            rebuildListView();
```

And this is my listAdapter class:

```
private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    // Bind the data to different textView for each rows
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trans_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_ddate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayDate);

            viewHolder.txt_ddesc = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayDesc);

            viewHolder.txt_dcat = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayCat);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_ddate.setText(_translist.get(position).getDate()
                .trim());

        viewHolder.txt_ddesc.setText(_translist.get(position)
                .getTransDescription().trim());

        viewHolder.txt_dcat.setText(_translist.get(position).getCategory()
                .trim());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

However, my problem now is let's say I got record 1,2 and 3 first. Then when I added another record which is 4, the list view supposed to show me 1-4 only. But with my codes, what I am getting is **1,2,3,1,2,3,4**. I wonder why the listAdapter keep on stacking the record although I set it to null and rebuild it again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your BuilListView method where you define ArrrayList, try this : ArrayList<TransactionRecModel> trans_list = new ArrayList<TransactionRecModel>;
 trans_list = trc.getTransactionRec(session_userID);

Comment: @Dhaval What does it do?

Comment: Try changing to my lines. It will create a new arraylist, so no old records.

Comment: Thanks! Your codes work too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not clearing the old list data. you have remove the old records from the list.

```
    public void builtListView() {
    _translist.clear();
    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
            mDbHelper.open());

    ArrayList<TransactionRecModel> trans_list = trc
            .getTransactionRec(session_userID);

    for (int i = 0; i < trans_list.size(); i++) {
        String date = trans_list.get(i).getDate();
        String categoryName = trans_list.get(i).getCategory();
        String transDesc = trans_list.get(i).getTransDescription();

        TransactionRecModel _TransModel = new TransactionRecModel();

        _TransModel.setDate(date);
        _TransModel.setCategory(categoryName);
        _TransModel.setTransDescription(transDesc);

        _translist.add(_TransModel);
    }
    // Set the data into listview
    listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

or you can reassign the values

```
  public void builtListView() {
    _translist.clear();
    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
            mDbHelper.open());

    _translist = trc
            .getTransactionRec(session_userID);

     // Set the data into listview
    listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```